# RecyclerView items doesn't wrap the content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layoutparams

I'm facing this issue:
I have recyclerview that shows images I've searched for but the items in recyclerview appears like their height is `math_parent` here's an example..

[image]

This is my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is `item_results.xml` (recyclerview item layout):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_shape2"
    android:clipToOutline="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the layout manager I used in `MainActivity.java:onCreate` for recyclerview:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    result.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
```

And this is `ResultBaseAdapter` class:

```
public class ResultBaseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultBaseAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    
    ArrayList<String> data;
    Context context;
    
    public ResultBaseAdapter(ArrayList<String> urls, Context context) {
        this.data = urls;
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_result, null);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        
        holder.getMain().setClipToOutline(true);
        
        String url = stringlist.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).toString();
        
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
            .into(holder.getImage());
            
        holder.getImage().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("link", stringlist.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stringlist.size();
    }
    
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        
        private ImageView image;
        private LinearLayout main;
        
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
            main = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.main);
        }
        
        public ImageView getImage() {
            return this.image;
        }
        
        public LinearLayout getMain() {
            return this.main;
        }
    }
}
```

So what's wrong here, I wants items to wrap the content in height not like math parent. And thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi As per my understanding you need to change your item layout to look like this

Only one change in height. please use it and confirm

**android:layout_height="match_parent"**

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout for the recycler view:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_shape2"
    android:clipToOutline="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```